# Check if variable is 0 and not empty

Tags: php

I'm using a form to post values to my PHP class.

```
<?php
    if(!empty($_POST)){
        require_once('../../handling/admin_add_user.php');

        $add_username = $_POST['add_username'];
        $add_email = $_POST['add_email'];
        $add_gender = $_POST['add_gender'];
        $add_server = $_POST['add_server'];
        $add_coins = $_POST['add_coins'];

        $user_add = new admin_add_user($add_username, $add_email, $add_gender, $add_server, $add_coins);
        $user_add_response = $user_add->class_handler();
        echo $user_add_response;
    }
?>
```

And inside the function `class_handler` im checking if the value for the `$this->coins` parameter is empty using the `isset function` sadly the function would always return the error message incase i would put a **0** as value.

```
<?php
    class admin_add_user extends database {
        function __construct($username, $email, $gender, $server, $coins){
            $this->username = $username;
            $this->email = $email;
            $this->gender = $gender;
            $this->server = $server;
            $this->coins = $coins;
        }

        function add_user(){
            $this->connect();
            $this->execute_query("INSERT INTO Users (username, email, gender, server, active, activate_key, coins) VALUES ('" . $this->username . "', '" . $this->email . "', '" . $this->gender . "', '" . $this->server . "', 1, 0, " . $this->coins . ")");
        }

        function class_handler(){
            if(!$this->username){
                return 'Please enter a username.';
            }else if(!$this->email){
                return 'Please enter a email.';
            }else if(!$this->gender){
                return 'Please select a gender.';
            }else if(!$this->server){
                return 'Please select a server.';
            }else if(isset($this->coins)){
                return 'Please enter a coin value. eG: 0';
            }else{
                $this->add_user();
                return 'Succesfull added the following account to the database: ' . $this->username;
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

How could I manage to check if the `$this->coins` variable **is NOT empty but could contain the int 0**?

Answer (score 2):

I think this should Work:

```
(isset($this->coins) && $this->coins == 0)
```

If not then Kindly post your Full Error Message

Answer (score 0):

To check if a variable is set you can use:

```
isset( $this->coins );
```

that return `True` also if the variable is set to 0;

To check if the variable is set to zero, you have to use:

```
$this->coins === 0;
```

Comment: == also done the trick, though === is good, it will also check the Datatype.. :)

Comment: @Arshi ` == ` return True also is variable is empty or doesn't exists.

Answer (score 0):

Since the value is coming from `POST` it is always a string. You should do something like:

```
(isset($this->coins) && (!empty($this->coins) || $this->coins === '0'))
```

[empty()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) will not work in this case. Because `'0'` still means empty.

Answer (score 0):

Use [!empty](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) in this case:-

```
!empty($this->coins) //true if $this->coins is neither 0, empty, or set at all';
```

Is enough.